# Python string analyze, counting a substrings error

Tags: python, string, counting

I try count substring in my string in Python.

```
string = "aaaaahehabdha" 

x = string.index("he") #5
y = string.rindex("ha") #11
z = y - x + 2 #lenght of substring 11 - 5 + 2 = 8

a = []
a.append(string.count("he", x, z)) #1
a.append(string.count("ha", x, z)) #count only once"ha" but in substring I have 2 x "ha"
print(a) # [1,1]
```

Why string.count("ha", x, z) counting only once "ha" ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of `.count` is not a length, but a non-inclusive ending index.  To compute the correct end point:

```
z = y + 2
```

Example, including comment example, computing correct substring from `he` to `ha`:

```
string = "aaaaahehabdha" 
x = string.index("he")
y = string.rindex("ha")
z = y + 2
print('substring:',string[x:z])

string = "aaaaahehabdhaaaaaaaaaaa" 
x = string.index("he")
y = string.rindex("ha")
z = y + 2
print('substring:',string[x:z])
```

Output:

```
substring: hehabdha
substring: hehabdha
```

Comment: @WaterInButtle But you compute a length, not an end index.  You're using  start,end of 6,8 when it should be 6,13.

Comment: But what if I have "aaaaahehabdhaaaaaaaa" I want count only in hehabdha substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just count the amount of "ha's" are in the substring, you only have to use `string.count("ha")` which will return 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments `x` and `z` are the start and end indices for where to search in the string, but the start index is always inclusive and end index is always noninclusive. You stored in `z` the length after the start index that you wanted to search from, when you really should have called

```
a.append(string.count("ha", x, y+1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Victor. I type: a.append(string.count("ha", x, string.rindex("ha")+2)) and now it will be ok.